# How to use spell checking in PO mode for gettext translations files?

Tags: flyspell, spell-checking, translation

I've tried function I use my my Markdown and Polymode when editing my Jekyll blog with po-mode but it don't work at all:

I have code like this:

```lisp
(defun lang (lang)
  (interactive "sLanguage: ")
  (ispell-change-dictionary lang)
  (flyspell-buffer))
```

when I run lang `polish` it process the file but nothing happen even if do error in one the translation.

I was looking at https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PoMode

but this don't work.

How can I get error checking inside PO file so I know that I need to edit the entry and fix the error.

It would also be nice to have error checking while editing.

Comment: Two ideas: 1. you forgot `(turn-on-flyspell)`?   2. `lang` should not be `polish`, but something in spirit of `en_US` (pl_PL?)?

Comment: running `flyspell-mode` and `lang pl_PL` give same results, no spell checking.